# Why am I getting the same angle by inputting different values of n in the general solution?

Tags: trigonometry

**Problem:**

Solve: $\sqrt{3}\sin x-\cos x=2$, $-2\pi<x<2\pi$

**My attempt:**

$$\sqrt{3}\sin x-\cos x=2$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\cos x=1$$

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}).\sin x-\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos x=1$$

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\cos x-\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}).\sin x=-1$$

$$\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{3})=\cos{\pi}$$

$$x+\frac{\pi}{3}=2n\pi\pm\pi, \text{where $n$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$}$$

$$x=2n\pi\pm\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Now, if $n=0$,

$$x=\frac{2\pi}{3},-\frac{4\pi}{3}$$

If $n=1$,

$$x=\frac{8\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}$$

If n=-1,

$$x=-\frac{4\pi}{3}, -\frac{10\pi}{3}$$

So, in the given interval, $x=\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{-4\pi}{3}$ (Ans.)

**Question:**

When $n=0$, and when $n=1$, I get $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Similarly, when $n=0$, and when $n=-1$, I get $-\frac{4\pi}{3}$. Why am I getting the same angle twice for different values of $n$?

Comment: There is only one solution. All other solutions you found differ by a multiple of $2\pi$ and are hence equivalent.

Comment: "$x+\frac{\pi}{3}=2n\pi\pm\pi$" One can write $x+\frac{\pi}{3}=2n\pi+\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x=2n\pi\pm\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}\\=-\frac{\pi}{3}+\pi(\color{red}{2n\pm1}).$$

$\color{red}{2n\pm1}:\quad\dots,-7,-7,-5,-5,-3,-3,-1,-1,1,1,3,3,5,5,\ldots.$

When solving trigonometric equations generally and the cosine or secant of the generating solution equals $-1,$ then $\color{red}{2n\pm1}$ occurs, giving rise to repeating/overlapping solutions.

This is inconsequential since the obtained collection of solutions is exhaustive anyway.